# C# Custom Message handler not giving headers values in web api

Tags: c#, http-headers

I have implemented MessageHandlers:

```
    config.MessageHandlers.Add(new TokenValidationHandler());
```

And When I Check on request to get Custom Header in request.I am getting Name of the Header Not a value Can someone help:

Please check ScreenShot.

And the same thing which I want is done using postman but when the origin is different is not happening.

How Cors Are enable:

```
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);
```

What i need is when i am passing custom header From different origin:

**'hitesh':'Token'**

I need this in Custom Header But i am getting 'hitesh' in Access **Control Access Request Headers.**

> Note: Cors are Enable:

```
 protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

    }
```

[image]
[image]